# Perform schema validation on array indexes in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've an array which contain strings and numbers. I know which array index will contain numbers and which will contain strings. Is there a better way to validate the type than this?
All the values in the array will be stored as string, but for the values I expect an integer it should be a valid number stored in a string format. If a string is expected it has to be any string and should not be a number (can be alphanumeric).

Say there can be only 5 indexes in the array:

```
[0]-> Integer
[1] -> String
[2] -> String
[3] -> Integer
[4] -> String

var validArray = ["145", "test1", "test", "1233", "blah"];

function validateArray() {
   if(isNaN(validArray[0]) || isNaN(validArray[3])) {
      return false;
   }
   if(!isNaN(validArray[1]) || !isNaN(validArray[2] || !isNaN(validArray[4])) {
      return false;
   }

}
```

Other option is I could splits into multiple if statements so that I know which index is causing the issue.

Is there a cleaner way to do this in NodeJS?  (validate array and indicate which index is causing the problem if any error is present).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this problem with creating a more generic validation function which we could then use as validator for different shape of data.

```
// Expected shape
const t = [
  "Number",
  "String",
  "String",
  "Number",
  "String",
]

// Test data - valid
const d = ["1", "a", "b", "2", "c"]
// Test data - invalid
const dInvalid = ["b", "a", "b", "2", "c"]

function validate(data, types) {
  // Map through shape
  return types.map((item, i) => {
    switch(item){
      // Switch by type and do expected comparison
      case "Number": return !Number.isNaN(Number(data[i]))
      case "String": return Number.isNaN(Number(data[i]))
      default: return false // Example defaults to false which might not be what you want 
    }
  })
}

console.log(validate(d, t)) // => [true, true, true, true, true]
console.log(validate(dInvalid, t)) // => [false, true, true, true, true]

//If want to check array validity
const valid = validate(d, t)

console.log(valid.every(item => item === true)) // => true
// OR
console.log(!valid.includes(false)) // true
```

> edit. added function to return invalid indexes

```
function invalidIndexes(data){
  let indexes = []
  data.forEach((item, i) => {
    if(item === false){ indexes.push(i) }
  })
  return indexes // example output. [1,3]
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to find out which indexes are incorrect

Comment: All indexes which are `false` are incorrect. I updated the answer with function to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a cleaner way of doing it natively:

```
function arrayIsValid(arr) {
  return [0, 3].every(function(n){return Number.isInteger(parseInt(arr[n], 10))}) &&
         [1, 2, 4].every(function(n){return typeof arr[n] == 'string' && !Number.isInteger(parseInt(arr[n], 10))})
};
```

As ES6:

```
function arrayIsValid(arr) {
  return [0, 3].every(n => Number.isInteger(parseInt(arr[n], 10))) &&
         [1, 2, 4].every(n => typeof arr[n] == 'string' && !Number.isInteger(parseInt(arr[n], 10)))
};
```

If the respective indexes of string and integer positions vary you can replace the static arrays with variables containing the relevant indexes.

Comment: Number.Integer returns false for "123" and in my case i need it as true since all indexes are stored as string. Also is there a nice way to show which index is causing an error if any

Comment: Sorry, did not read your post well enough, but the code is now updated to handle integers formatted as strings. The latter is not easy to accomplish with this code.

Comment: No worries. This is nice style.

Answer (score 0):

If the type of every index is pre-defined or known in advance, then you can use `Map` to capture the expected indices against a particular type. `Key` can be anything that indicates a particular type, like in the example below I have used `true` to define `Number` and `false` to define `String` (You have already mentioned in your post that there will be Number and String only).

```js
var typed = new Map();
typed.set(true, [0, 3]);
typed.set(false, [1, 2, 4]);
var validArray = ["145", "test1", "test", "1233", "blah"];
var invalidArray = ["145test", "test1", "test", "1233", "blah"];

function validate(validArray) {
  for (var i = 0; i < validArray.length; i++) {
    var type = !isNaN(validArray[i]);
    if (!typed.get(type).includes(i)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
console.log(validate(validArray));
console.log(validate(invalidArray));
```

Using the above function you will also know which `index` is failing validation.

Hope this will help!

Comment: Hmm that works, but I see 2 problems with this approach, if there is a 3rd type which I'm interested in validating, then I will need to move from the boolean approach. Also with boolean approach it is hard to relate that this is used to store string/integer status

Comment: I have already mentioned in the answer that I have chosen boolean as you have mentioned about 2 types in the question only, yes it has a limitation that for the 3rd type it will fail, you need to figure out the `key` for the 3rd type. Rest of the concept will remain the same.